# Shell function to check if there is a suspended process that's a child of this shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, background-process, jobs

I'd like to add an indicator to my PS1, showing whether there is a process suspended with ctrl+z. In order to do so, I'll need a function that is able to check for this situation. I'm not even sure where to start to think about this problem. Google has failed me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Process suspended with Ctrl+Z” is actually a subset of “suspended process that's a child of this shell”, and it's easier to track: that means there's a suspended background job.

In zsh, you can check the [`jobstates` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-jobstates).

```
if ((${(M)#jobstates:#suspended:*} == 0)); then
  echo There are no suspended jobs
else
  echo There are ${(M)#jobstates:#suspended:*} suspended jobs
fi
```

In bash or zsh, `jobs -s` lists only suspended jobs.

```
echo "There are $(jobs -s | wc -l) suspended jobs"
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @JoshuaD At a guess, I'd say my nemesis. (I have a nemesis on this site :-() Don't worry about it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Zsh 5.5.1. If I simply do `echo ${#jobstates}`, that does indeed display a `1` when I have suspended a process.

Comment: @henrebotha What “doesn't work”? But looking again at the code in this answer, the first snippet was showing the number of _non-suspended_ jobs instead of the number of suspended jobs. Is that the problem you encountered?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I got a `0` regardless of whether there were any suspended jobs. The new version works correctly. Though `${#jobstates:#suspended}` seems to yield the same result.